# iText getting data from a PL/SQL procedure

Tags: java, plsql, itext

I want to obtain a pdf through a procedure with iText on the Database. For example the call is :

```
Connection con = null;

String call = "{call COFRUTIL.CCVRecup('1', -25, '60888', 'BASJO9201')}";

CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall(call);
```

And then what I should write so that the pdf content goes into a PdfReader ? The PL/SQL package procedure which return the PDF runs properly because when we go through the application server it works. I found a lot of pages on the Net where the pdf is obtained with a select. However I found nothing when we go through a procedure. Can we do it ?

Thanks,

Pierrick

Comment: This question is not really related to iText: You retrieve the data from the result set as you would do for other consuming libraries, too. How you do that, depends on what that procedure does.

Comment: But to use a result set there must have a SELECT statement I think ? Here there is no SELECT statement. The main part of the PLSQL procedure is :                                                while l_off < len loop
         dbms_lob.read( pdf_lob, l_amt , l_off , l_raw);
         htp.prn( utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(l_raw) );
         l_off := l_off+l_amt;
      end loop; Can you help ? thanks, Pierrick

Comment: Have you tried whether you can execute that `CallableStatement` as a query? I.e. `ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()`? If that works, you can inspect `rs`...

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. I already tried that with stmt.execute(); alone. I can call the PLSQL package but I get a owa_util.mime_header(l_mime); ORA-06512: at "SYS.OWA_UTIL", line 356
ORA-06512: à "SYS.HTP", line 1368
ORA-06512: à "SYS.HTP", line 1443
ORA-06512: à "SYS.OWA_UTIL", line 413 I searched the web about java calling plsql procedure with this error on the mime header and I found nothing helpfull Can you help me please ? Thanks, a lot Pierrick

Comment: To be more secific the line is owa_util.mime_header('application/pdf');

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea concerning those messages. If you try once again to post a question on this issue, you might want to include the extra information you gave in the comments here already in the question to start with. Many readers here just track the incoming original questions...